# Warning: Trying to access array offset on value of type null in C:

Tags: php, arrays, model-view-controller, pdo, offset

Hi I have been working all this week on this project that I'm helping my son with for his school project, the project is a PHP login script using the MVC design everything runs but I keep getting the following Warning: Trying to access array offset on value of type null in C:\wamp64\www\mvcloginregister\app\libraries\Core.php on line 18, line 18 is the following code:

```
// Look in BLL for first value
 18 if(file_exists('../app/controllers/' . ucwords($url[0]). '.php')){
    // If exists, set as controller
    $this->currentController = ucwords($url[0]);
    // Unset 0 Index
    unset($url[0]);
  }
I think the issue is in the following function 
public function getUrl(){
  if(isset($_GET['url'])){
    $url = rtrim($_GET['url'], '/');
    $url = filter_var($url, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL);
    $url = explode('/', $url);
    return $url;
  }
}
```

I have reviewed all recommended answer related to this issue on this site and I'm unable to fix this issue I also found a post on google with the same issue but the person who fixed the issue did not post the solution which I think is rude and unprofessional. Please help I'm very new to this php language and the MVC design.

Comment: The `$url` variable doesn't exist, but you're treating it as if it exists and contains an array. Note that, as written, `getUrl()` doesn't return anything if the `url` parameter is absent from the URL. You probably want to detect this condition and serve a 404 page when it happens.

Comment: the $url variable does exist  $url = $this->getUrl();

      // Look in BLL for first value
      if(file_exists('../app/controllers/' . ucwords($url[0]). '.php')){
        // If exists, set as controller
        $this->currentController = ucwords($url[0]);
        // Unset 0 Index
        unset($url[0]);
      }

Comment: `$url = $this->getUrl();` Ok, well you did not include that in your original post. Still, it's empty, but your code assumes it will always be an array that contains at least one element.

Answer (score 0):

Today I had the same problem and also couldn't find any solution around the web.
Finally I've solved it by myself: added the $url variable to the condition inside the "if" statement. this checks not only if the file exists but also if $url isn't null - like so:

```
 $url = $this->getUrl();
 
  if( $url && file_exists('../app/controllers/' . ucwords($url[0]). '.php') ){
   
    $this->currentController = ucwords($url[0]);
    
    unset($url[0]);
  }
```